# Issues exporting animation to FBX in Blender 2.90

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I am pretty new to blender and so I started off simple with this wolf animation. The problem occurs when I try to export to FBX. I have been searching the internet for a day or so now but no solutions have worked. My weights are all 1.0 for each bone and I have followed the export methods of countless forums.
[image]
[image]

My biggest clue for my problem is when I go into edit mode.
[image]

As you can see, my mesh (and also rig) is very tiny compared to the object mode. I am at a loss for how to fix this though. My limited experience with this and UE4 tell me it is some small setting I am glossing over. Any insights would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: Did you apply (ctrl A) the scale of both mesh and rig before exporting? BTW there's no need of having all weights at 1.0. Be aware that applying scale should be performed before animation: every previously made animation will break.

Comment: Hey @joshsanfelici, I did apply the scale to the mesh and rig before exporting. And weights were already at 1.0 but I read from a [previous post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116683/unity-model-is-distorting-when-animation-is-running) that differing weights could produce something similar to what I am seeing.

Comment: I think it's a problem of scaling, because every bone that have only rotation informations do their job, while those having also loc infos appear to have a bigger influence than they should (you can try to scale on Y in graph editor every loc related keyframe). The animation seems to have been done before correctly applying scale. Try also to set the armature in rest pose, then apply the armature modifier of the wolf, then add a new armature modifier pointing at the rig (you will not loose the weights in this way).